# Java XML pharsing deleting node

Tags: java, xml-parsing

Java code required for doing the below operation.
Im having an xml as string, for example

```
<EMpData>
<Employee1>
  <Address1>XYZ<Address1/>
  <city>DDD<city/>
<Employee1/>
<Employee2>
  <Address1><Address1/>
  <city><city/>
<Employee2/>
<EMpData/>
```

I have to check if any child node is empty or null or without value, if it is there then i have to delete the parent and child nodes. So in above employee2 is empty , i want the below output

```
<EMpData>
<Employee1>
  <Address1>XYZ<Address1/>
  <city>DDD<city/>
<Employee1/>
<EMpData/>
```

Please Suggest the best and efficient way to do this. The actual xml will be about 500 to 700 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code based on XPath and VTD-XML..

```
import java.io.*;
import com.ximpleware.*;

public class removeNode2 {
    public static void main(String s[]) throws VTDException, IOException{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        String xml = "<EMpData>\n"+
                "<Employee1>\n"+
                "<Address1>XYZ</Address1>\n"+
                "<city>DDD</city>\n"+
                "</Employee1>\n"+
                "<Employee2>\n"+
                "<Address1></Address1>\n"+
                "<city></city>\n"+
                "</Employee2>\n"+
                "</EMpData>\n";
        vg.setDoc(xml.getBytes());
        vg.parse(false);
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier(vn);
        ap.selectXPath("/EMpData/*[string-length(*/text())=0]");

        int i=0;
        while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
            //System.out.println(" -====>"+ap2.evalXPathToBoolean());
            xm.remove();
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        xm.output(baos);
        System.out.println(baos.toString());
    }
}
```